# Actionfunction is not working on onchange event

Tags: apex, apexactionfunction

I am trying to call actionFuction on selectlist onchange event but It is not working (function not going to called)

Can anybody tell me what wrong in my code and the best practices follow when using Ajax component

Below is the code for your reference:

Apex Page:

```
<apex:page controller="BucketImageController" action="{!constructors}">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:PageBlock >
            <apex:selectList value="{!BucketList}" size="1" onChange="ShowAllImages();" >
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Buckets}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:actionFunction name="ShowAllImages" action="{!DisplayAllImages}" />   
            <apex:outputPanel id="out"> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!BucketList}"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:PageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
 public String[] getBucketList() {
    return BucketList;
}

public void setBucketList(String[] BucketList) {
    this.BucketList = BucketList;
}

/* ----------- End Properties Declaration Block ------------------*/    

/* ----------- Methods Declaration Block -------------------------*/
public PageReference constructors(){
    try{

        credentials = new AWSKeys(AWSCredentialName);
        as3 = new S3.AmazonS3(credentials.key,credentials.secret);

        }catch(AWSKeys.AWSKeysException AWSEx){
         System.debug('Caught exception in AWS_S3_ExampleController: ' + AWSEx);
         ApexPages.Message errorMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, AWSEx.getMessage());
         ApexPages.addMessage(errorMsg);

    }   

   return null; 
}   



public List<SelectOption> getBuckets() {


    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    Datetime now = Datetime.now();
    S3.ListAllMyBucketsResult allBuckets = as3.ListAllMyBuckets(as3.key,now,as3.signature('ListAllMyBuckets',now));

    S3.ListAllMyBucketsList BucketList=allBuckets.Buckets;
    S3.ListAllMyBucketsEntry[] buckets=BucketList.Bucket;

    bucketname=new string[]{};

    for(S3.ListAllMyBucketsEntry bkt :buckets)
        bucketname.add(bkt.name);

    for(string bktName:bucketname )
    {
        options.add(new SelectOption(bktName,bktName));
    }

    return options;

    }   


public void DisplayAllImages()
{
        system.debug('#######' + BucketList);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

actionFunction is not working because you are not using "rerender" attribute in actionFunction. There is a bug in VF pages related to actionFuntion that it will work only if you use rerender attribute. So, you have to add rerendere="none" or any element id that you want to rerender , but i think if you use rerender="none" it will work for you.

`<apex:actionFunction name="ShowAllImages" action="{!DisplayAllImages}" rerender="none"/>`.

Hope this will help you!!!

Comment: hi tandonprateek, I added rerender attribute with outputpanel id still it is not working

Comment: Can u please move your actionFunction out from <apex:pageBlock> and paste it after <apex:form> then try. I think it should work.

Comment: My Page is working fine now... There was mistake in the code that i was trying to pass BucketList value which is of type string[] to selectlist and also i maintained size attribute on selectlist as size=1. I changed BucketList to type string. Now its working